# Create new column with distinct character values

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
color <- c("red","red","red","blue","green","green","blue",
           "yellow","red","red","blue","green")
df <- data.frame(ID,color)
```

I wish to have: the "color" column to only contain the distinct colors.
So ID 1 has 7 observations with repeated colors but I want it to show just the distinct colors, so that ID 1 would have only 3 observations because it only has 3 distinct colors. etc

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
n_color <- c(3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
color <- c("red","blue","green",
           "yellow","red","blue","green")
df <- data.frame(ID,n_color,color)
```

I know I can use the following to summarize the distinct number of colors but I couldn't figure out how to do what I wanted( mentioned above).

```
df%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 summarize(n=n_distinct(color))%>%
 ungroup()
```

Is there a way to do this? I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct(color, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  mutate(n_color = n(), .after = ID) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     ID n_color color 
  <dbl>   <int> <chr> 
1     1       3 red   
2     1       3 blue  
3     1       3 green 
4     2       4 yellow
5     2       4 red   
6     2       4 blue  
7     2       4 green
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` from *base* to get unique rows from `df`.

```
unique(df)
#   ID  color
#1   1    red
#4   1   blue
#5   1  green
#8   2 yellow
#9   2    red
#11  2   blue
#12  2  green
```

In case only specific columns should be used `duplicated` can be used and its result be inverted with `!` to select the unique rows with `[`.

```
df[!duplicated(df),]
#   ID  color
#1   1    red
#4   1   blue
#5   1  green
#8   2 yellow
#9   2    red
#11  2   blue
#12  2  green
```

In case also the number of colors is needed `ave` could be used.

```
transform(unique(df), n_color = ave(ID, ID, FUN=length))
#   ID  color n_color
#1   1    red       3
#4   1   blue       3
#5   1  green       3
#8   2 yellow       4
#9   2    red       4
#11  2   blue       4
#12  2  green       4
```