# Create new column with frequency of values

Tags: r, frequency

This is similar to my previous questions posted: [Create new column with distinct character values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989498/create-new-column-with-distinct-character-values)

But I also wanted some additional information.

df:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
color <- c("red","red","red","blue","green","green","blue",
           "yellow","yellow","red","blue","green")
df <- data.frame(ID,color)

   ID  color
1   1    red
2   1    red
3   1    red
4   1   blue
5   1  green
6   1  green
7   1   blue
8   2 yellow
9   2 yellow
10  2    red
11  2   blue
12  2  green
```

Creating n_distinct_color (number of distinct colors each ID has):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct(color, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  mutate(n_distinct_color = n(), .after = ID) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 × 3
     ID n_distinct_color color 
  <dbl>            <int> <chr> 
1     1                3 red   
2     1                3 blue  
3     1                3 green 
4     2                4 yellow
5     2                4 red   
6     2                4 blue  
7     2                4 green
```

Now I want to create:

1. new "Frequency" column that shows how many times each color appears for each ID (From original df, ID 1 has 3 red, 2 blue, 2 green, etc)
2. new "most frequent color" column that shows which color is the most frequent for each ID. (From original df, most frequent color for ID1 is red, for ID2 is yellow.)

```
     ID n_distinct_color color    frequency_of_color   most_frequent_color 
  <dbl>            <int> <chr>    <int>                <chr>
1     1                3 red      3                    red
2     1                3 blue     2                    red
3     1                3 green    2                    red
4     2                4 yellow   2                    yellow
5     2                4 red      1                    yellow
6     2                4 blue     1                    yellow
7     2                4 green    1                    yellow
```

Also, what if there's a case where there are 2 colors with the same frequency (ie, ID 2's most frequent color are yellow and red, how will the data table be like?)

df_new:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
color <- c("red","red","red","blue","green","green","blue",
           "yellow","yellow","red","blue","green","red")
df_new <- data.frame(ID,color)

   ID  color
1   1    red
2   1    red
3   1    red
4   1   blue
5   1  green
6   1  green
7   1   blue
8   2 yellow
9   2 yellow
10  2    red
11  2   blue
12  2  green
13  2    red
```

I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a series of `mutate` and `summarise` you can achieve your goal. In case of ties, here `[1]` means the first tied color is chosen:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 or above required
df %>% 
  mutate(n_distinct = n_distinct(color), .by = ID) %>% 
  summarise(frequency = n(), .by = c(ID, n_distinct, color)) %>% 
  mutate(most_frequent = color[which.max(frequency)[1]], .by = ID)
```

output

```r
  ID n_distinct  color frequency most_frequent
1  1          3    red         3           red
2  1          3   blue         2           red
3  1          3  green         2           red
4  2          4 yellow         2        yellow
5  2          4    red         2        yellow
6  2          4   blue         1        yellow
7  2          4  green         1        yellow
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very concise and clear answer!